# special characters match in htaccess redirect .com?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I trying to create a SEO friendly url in the format like this

```
http://web_url/news/**news_title**/**newsid**
```

which is redirected to

```
http://web_url/index.php?t=news&newsid=newsid
```

I wrote the following .htaccess rule but it fails as long as the url format has no special characters but once a special character is present in the url, it fails

```
eg. http://web_url/news/mywebsite.com is live!/4
```

Here are my rules:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?t=news&newsid=$2

RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?t=news&newsid=$2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Like what sort of special characters? Your expression permits hyphens or underscores only.

Comment: Also please clarify, you want it to work when there is no special characters and fail otherwise, but it is currently failing for everything? You can also combine both rules by making the last `/` optional with `/?` on the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?t=news&newsid=$2
```

instead of both rules.